# Solution for split root directory

Tags: php

I get document root with :

```
realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

The output of this code like:

```
//If Windows
C:/wamp/www
```

Or

```
//If Linux
/home/test/public_html
```

We conclude that the output should be either.
I need to a code or solution with the following specifications:
If my server is Windows convert `C:/wamp/www` TO `C:/`
And if my server is Linux convert `/home/test/public_html` TO `/home/`

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: what like `realpath('/');`?

Comment: `realpath('/');` worked only on windows.

Comment: This is [relatively simple](http://dk1.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php). Please show us what you have tried so far, and ask a *specific question*.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Won't work for both cases not what OP is expecting.

Comment: @RahilWazir Yeah, well, it does not take much to make it work for both cases. But then again, people who ask for the solution are rarely motivated enought to figure stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do this

### With Regex:

```
$realpath = '/home/test/public_html';
// or
$realpath = 'C:/wamp/www';

preg_match_all('/(\/?[^\/]+\/)/', $realpath, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1][0]); // C:/ or /home/
```